# script to swap strings containing newlines within text file (XML)

Tags: text-processing, xml

I am using Arch which was updated a couple of weeks ago. Packages is use are

- Arch 6.0.10-arch2-1
- BASH 5.1.16(1)-release
- gnu sed 4.9
- gnu grep 3.8
- openbox 3.6.1

Within my Openbox `rc.xml` text file I have two lines as follows

```
<!-- <keybind key="Right"> -->

<keybind key="s-Up">
```

I wish to frequently toggle/swap the above two lines for the below two lines using a script

```
<!-- <keybind key="s-Up"> -->

<keybind key="Right">
```

This allows me to quickly change a keybinding without tediously editing my keybindings set-up text file (`rc.xml`) every time.

The script I have so far is below, and is not working, though I know it is close.

I'm not too bothered how this toggling is achieved, but having spent a significant amount of time already on this it would be nice to get below script working.

The `sed` expressions below that do the text swapping work as they should.

The `if` statement seems to do the first `sed` swap if the condition is met but not the second `sed` swap if the condition is not met, which is the issue.

```
var_a=""

#var_a=$(grep -zoP  "<\!\-\- <keybind key=\"Right\"> \-\->\n\n<keybind key=\"s-Up\">" /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s|\n\n||g')

var_a=$(grep -zoP  "<\!\-\- <keybind key=\"Right\"> \-\->\n\n<keybind key=\"s-Up\">" /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml | tr -d '\n' )

# result of grep is
# <!-- <keybind key="Right"> --><keybind key="s-Up">

echo $var_a; sleep 0.5

#if [[ -z ! "$var_a" ];then
if [[ '$var_a'=='<!-- <keybind key="Right"> --><keybind key="s-Up">' ]]; then

   sed -ie ':a;N;$!ba;s|<!-- <keybind key="Right"> -->\n\n<keybind key="s-Up">|<!-- <keybind key="s-Up"> -->\n\n<keybind key="Right">|g' /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

else

   sed -ie ':a;N;$!ba;s|<!-- <keybind key="s-Up"> -->\n\n<keybind key="Right">|<!-- <keybind key="Right"> -->\n\n<keybind key="s-Up">|g' /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml

fi
```

Comment: Please, post xml and expected output

Comment: @Kusalananda I put 'test' in as a tag because the script apparently fails on the if statement. In BASH if is also known as 'test'

Comment: @Gilles Quenot the xml is in the post. The failing script is intended to replace the first blocks of xml at the top of the post with the block just underneath that. Then switch them again, second to first. And keep toggling them to change the order as  required.

Comment: Is that the whole file? A single unclosed XML tag?  Why do you need the commend-out tag at all?

Comment: I removed the tags as the question is about text-processing, not about the sed, grep or test utilities.

Comment: It's not valid XML

Comment: The whole xml file is thousands of lines long and contains personal stuff. This is the exact portion that needs to be changed. None of the rest of the file is relevant as it is not changed by the script. This is from my Opebbox xml config. This is the totality (everything on) lines 2015 to 2017 in the file. This is the structure that Openbox is using.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, fair enough, as you say 'if' and 'test' are different. I wonder if they are the same thing but just using a different name, or may be distinctly different utilities

Comment: @Kusalananda The OP did choose the `grep` and `sed` tags for a reason. Future users will likely choose the same tags for a similar problem, so the original tags could help them find the question. The `xml` and `text-processing` tags are a good addition, but not replacement, I think. It's similar to X-Y problems, where you better not remove the `X`-related tags.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think Philippos is right. The OP is concerned with getting **sed** & **grep** & the **bash if** statement to process text. It could be any text, even if it is xml. xml I think is less relevant to the question. In fact to me it is more or less irrelevant, becasue the core of this is about text replacement. Only a portion of the xml text within a valid xml tag structure needs to be replaced. For all the escapes etc was a relitavley complicated problem to face. Therefore I kept it as simple as possible with the least amount necessary to process. Solve the simplest problem first

Comment: @Philippos I removed them as the question is not about the use of those tools. By your way of reasoning, you'd have the [tag:linux] tag on any question where the user happens to be running Linux (which we actually seem to have, which makes the tag useless, which is my point).

Comment: @Kusalananda  since the OP uses those tools I can't by any reasonable means see how you reach that conclusion. I think you have deleted relevant tags without any good reason. The OP script uses those tools, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the condition will never be met, because the single quotes in `'$var_a'` will prevent your variable from getting expanded at all, so the literal string `$var_a` will never be equal to th other literal string.

Use double quotes and it should work, **but** I'd like to add some remarks about your script:

**(1)** You first do a `grep`, then base a condition on the contents you get from this `grep` and finally use two different `sed` script. This is likely to result in errors. Actually, your `sed` will do the whole thing alone:

```
sed -ie ':a;N;$!ba
  s|<!-- <keybind key="Right"> -->\n\n<keybind key="s-Up">|<!-- <keybind key="s-Up"> -->\n\n<keybind key="Right">|g
  t
  s|<!-- <keybind key="s-Up"> -->\n\n<keybind key="Right">|<!-- <keybind key="Right"> -->\n\n<keybind key="s-Up">|g' \
  /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

If the first replacement was made, the `t` jumps to the end of the script, otherwise the other replacement is performed. The `grep` and `if` is already included!

**(2)** You way to collect all lines `:a;N;$!ba` will only work in GNU `sed`, because according to the POSIX standard, everything after the colon will be the jump mark, no exception for `;`. No problem for you, because you have GNU `sed`, but then you also have the `-z` option to process the hole file in one run without the part. If you like it portable, `H;1h;$!d;x` does the same thing via the hold space.

**(3)** I think, the `g`lobal flag is superfluous, because those lines exist only once, correct?

**(4)** Writing the same stuff over and over, may cause error and is harder to read. Why not reuse one part by marking it with `\(\)` and referring to it as `\1`?

```
sed -iz 's|<!-- \(<keybind key="\)Right"> -->\n\n\1s-Up">|<!-- \1s-Up"> -->\n\n\1Right">|
  t
  s|<!-- \(<keybind key="\)s-Up"> -->\n\n\1Right">|<!-- \1Right"> -->\n\n\1s-Up">|' \
  /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

**(5)** Actually, you don't need to process the whole file as one (this can even cause overruns for large files), you only need to process every consecutive three lines together, using the `N;P;D` scheme (usually two lines together, adding `1N` to expand it to three lines):

```
sed -i '1N;N
  s|<!-- \(<keybind key="\)Right"> -->\n\n\1s-Up">|<!-- \1s-Up"> -->\n\n\1Right">|
  t
  s|<!-- \(<keybind key="\)s-Up"> -->\n\n\1Right">|<!-- \1Right"> -->\n\n\1s-Up">|;
  P;D' /home/kes/Dropbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

One could probably simplify this further, but this would require additional information about the file contents.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Appreciated :) I will come back with more comments

Comment: (1) I did not know an "if then else" conditional statement coule be done with sed. I have used it. It works as needed.

Comment: (1) is a remarkable addition to my knowledge

Comment: (2) I don't know POSIX portability standard well enough. But on a quick try I could not get your suggested substitution to work. I will come back to it later and study it. I presume by the z option you refer to grep

Comment: (3) yes the lines exist only once in the file. I have got used to using 'g' global as a catch all becasue usually there are multiple replacements to be made. Not in this case though.

Comment: (4) grouping with \\(...\\) xyz  \\(...\\)  --> \1 \2, yes of course. Very nice. I never got far enough to polish it up. Great suggestion, thank you

Comment: (5) that is very slick, and fully tested and working! You have encouraged me to take my journey with sed further

Comment: Also, I did change **'$var_a'** to **"$var_a"** and the result was the same. It would be nice to find out why the original script did not work. It may be because of the result within the grep which produced it's result on the command line before the terminal prompt and also sprung a  **"bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input"** error. I also think the conditionality of the **if** statement was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML document is well-formed and syntactically correct, you may use the XML processor `xmlstarlet` to toggle the values.

Ignoring the commented-out XML in the document,
the following achieves this by first changing all `key` attributes of every `keybind` node from the value `Right` to `temporary` (attributes with another value will not be affected).  It then changes the same attribute from `s-Up` to `Right` and finally from `temporary` to `s-Up`.  The string `temporary` is an arbitrary string that is otherwise not used for the `key` attribute of the `keybind` node.

This effectively swaps the values from `Right` to `s-Up` and vice versa.

```bash
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var attr '//keybind/@key' \
    --update '$attr[.="Right"]'     --value temporary \
    --update '$attr[.="s-Up"]'      --value Right \
    --update '$attr[.="temporary"]' --value s-Up \
   file.xml
```

This would turn a document like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <keybind key="s-Up"/>
  <keybind key="s-Down"/>
  <keybind key="Right"/>
</root>
```

... into

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <keybind key="Right"/>
  <keybind key="s-Down"/>
  <keybind key="s-Up"/>
</root>
```

If you insert `--inplace` directly after the `edit` word on the command line, the edit will be made in-place, modifying the original file.

Comment: that's a good solution thank you. I had not considered xmlstarlet. I now see why you wanted the full xml tag structure. I will test with that too, so that I learn from you. That is helpful. Appreciated.